# How to change the name of a tab in a browser opened by java

Tags: java, browser

So I have code which opens up a file in my documents in my browser with the code below:

```
OpenQuery(){
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        p.destroy();

        File folder = new File("C:/Users/SAVAGD05/Documents/RMP/QUERIES/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            String url = "C:/Users/Sammy/Documents/RMP/QUERIES/"
                    + listOfFiles[i].getName();
            File htmlFile = new File(url);
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI());


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

And at the moment this all works, but the tab at the top just shows the file path, whereas I would like it to show something a bit more meaningful. Is there a method/way of doing this or is it something built into the browser which you can't change without considerable effort?

Comment: Understand that when Java opens your browser via the Desktop class, it has no idea what type of browser is being opened, much less what operating system. I don't think that there is a direct way of doing this from this Java pathway.

Comment: you can make a browser extension for this(if you don't want to edit files for some reason)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with Java. The title is set by the documents which are displayed in the browser. Therefore, you need to edit the files inside `C:/Users/Sammy/Documents/RMP/QUERIES/`, adding an HTML `<title>` attribute to their head.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom page title <-- edit here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to add also, is three any way to change what is says in the search bar as well?

Comment: What do you mean by search bar? The Location bar that also displays the file name and location?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: No, that's not possible (with common browsers). If you want that, you might consider displaying a browser component inside your own app, instead of invoking an external one. I am not aware of any good libraries for this, though.